# Converting prime notation of derivatives to Leibniz notation.Resources needed

Tags: derivatives, notation

I have been studying calculus for past few months and through the time I have been using the so called prime notation.I have been studying from Spivaks Calculus for those of you who are familiar with the book.

My problem now is that I want to study some differential equations so I can study Lagrangian and Hamiltonian mechanics eventually,but the books that teach differential equations mostly use Leibniz notation which I am not familiar with.

Could some of you point me in direction where I can learn to use Leibniz notation and convert it to prime notation,and other way around as well?

Also I would appreciate if someone would layout examples of chain rule,multiplication rule and other basic differentiation rules expressed in Leibniz notation in comparision to prime notation.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Derivative:
$f'(x) = \dfrac {d}{dx} f(x) = \dfrac {df}{dx}(x) = \dfrac {df(x)}{dx} = \left.\dfrac {df}{dx}\right|_x$ and often also written simply as $\dfrac {df}{dx}$

Second Derivative:
$f''(x) = \dfrac {d^2}{dx^2}f(x) = \dfrac {d^2f}{dx^2}(x) = \dfrac {d^2f(x)}{dx^2} = \left.\dfrac {d^2f}{dx^2}\right|_x$ and often also written simply as $\dfrac {d^2f}{dx^2}$

The extension to higher derivatives should be obvious.

---

Chain rule: Let $y = g(x)$.
$(f\circ g)'(x) = f'(g(x))g'(x) \iff \dfrac {df}{dx} = \dfrac {df}{dy}\dfrac {dy}{dx}$

Product rule:
$(fg)'(x) = f'(x)g(x) + f(x) g'(x) \iff \dfrac d{dx} \big(f(x)g(x)\big) = \dfrac {df(x)}{dx}g(x) + f(x)\dfrac {dg(x)}{dx}$

Comment: This is one problem I have,how can we view function as general when we define it f(x)=y ?Does that not just mean that function is constant and always gives some y as result?But it seems to mean something else beside a constant fuction.Can you explain?

Comment: $f$ is the function.  $f(x)$ is the value of $f$ evaluated at the nonspecific value $x$.  Thus it is perfectly OK to have the equation $f(x) = y$, but it would not be correct to have $f=y$, unless you mean for $y$ to be a function, also.  It is a very common abuse of notation, however, for textbooks or professors to write "the function $f(x)$".

Comment: It makes me sad that mathematicians allow such abuse of notation,since it basically says that at different inputs the meaning of y as variable changes,which is very confusing.All in all a good answer